# Laravel - Override model ID

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

I'm working on an ebook management system. Instead of an auto-incrementing integer primary key, I'm using UUIDs, which works fine:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
    });
}
```

I also disabled PK incrementing on the model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Now the EPUB standard suggests publishers to assign every book a UUID, if possible, so I thought it would be neat to use an existing UUID if the file provides it, otherwise generate a new one for the library.
So I added `id` to the `$fillable` array of my model and set the ID conditionally in my `create` controller method:

```
if (array_key_exists('uuid', $epubMetaData)) {
    $book->id = $epubMetaData['uuid'];
}
```

Then I populate the rest of my fields and `$book->save()` the book. It ends up with a newly generated UUID, even if there is one in the `$epubMetaData` array... So I suspect Laravel decides to ignore my ID. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: name of primary key in model `id` or `uuid` ?

Comment: @J.Doe I used `id`

Comment: Also you should add ` public $keyType = 'string';` Otherwise you might have the same issues as me later down the road https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid/issues/48

Comment: @Geru thank you, just did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you aren't checking if the id is already set in your creating callback:

```
static::creating(function ($model) {
    if (!$model->id) {
       $model->id = Uuid::generate()->string;
    }
});
```

Comment: But shouldn't the flow of events be 1. create new model instance, 2. `creating` event is called, 3. ID property is modified, 4. model gets saved?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If the model is new, save() initiates both a creating and a created event.  creating is dispatched right before it is persisted to the database, created right after.

Comment: that was the problem - I had always thought the `creating` event is called after creating a model instance, not before persisting. Makes sense and your snippet solves the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To disable auto incrementing (and therefore the management of your id column by Laravel), you can add a public $incrementing property to your model and set it to false:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

You can also set a protected $primaryKey property in your model to override the default id column's name:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
```

Of course if your column is named "id", you don't have to do that.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, my `Book` model includes `public $incrementing = false;` already, I'll add it to the question. And the PK is named `id`, too.